# String split for specific element

Tags: java, regex

I need to split the following string only the data between the "CHAR" tabs:

Input:

```
<MSG><KEY>name.extObject</KEY><PARAM><CHAR>Number</CHAR><CHAR>7015:188188</CHAR></PARAM></MSG>
```

Expected output: `Number 7015:188188`

I am looking for something efficient.

Any recommendation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to capture the content between tags than splitting the string.

It's well known that you should **NOT** use a regex to parse xhtml since you can get w͈̦̝͉̬͔͕͡ͅe̴͏̰̜͖̗̤̙̖̕i̧̩̭̳̱̖̦͠ͅŗ̴̼̺̻͕̀d̶̩̖̦̖̲̣̺̫͘ ̡͇̥̩͓c͕̻̫͉̞͝ͅo̯̗͜͜͝ṇ̠͘t̛̬̮̞̥͕̙̞e̷̸̗̼͟ͅn̡͎̖̜̱͟͢t̨̙̫̻̱̺͈̗͝. Although, if you still want a regex you can use a regex like this:

```
<CHAR>(.*?)<\/CHAR>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO9cR7/1)**

And you can have this java code:

```
String line = "<MSG><KEY>name.extObject</KEY><PARAM><CHAR>Number</CHAR><CHAR>7015:188188</CHAR></PARAM></MSG>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<CHAR>(.*?)<\\/CHAR>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

String result = "";
while (matcher.find()) {
    result += matcher.group(1) + " ";
}
System.out.println(result); //Prints: Number 7015:188188
```

**Update**: as **[Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo)** pointed in his comment:

> `/` is not special character in Java regex engine. You don't have to escape it

So, you can use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<CHAR>(.*?)</CHAR>");
```

Btw, I really like [Pshemo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29570369/710099), it's a nice approach to solve this without regex and xhtml

Comment: `/` is not special character in Java regex engine. You don't have to escape it (it only creates confusion).

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to [avoid parsing XML/HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766). Instead you can use proper XML parser? I like to use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) so here is example how it can be done with this libraryL:

```
String data = "<MSG><KEY>name.extObject</KEY><PARAM><CHAR>Number</CHAR><CHAR>7015:188188</CHAR></PARAM></MSG>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data, "", Parser.xmlParser());
String charText = doc.select("CHAR").text();

System.out.println(charText);
```

Output: `Number 7015:188188`

Comment: I really like this approach, +1

Answer (score 0):

In case you know the tag value is always some digit, then an optional colon with digits, and it is the only `<CHAR>` tag that has such a numeric value, you may want to use this regex:

```
 (?<=<CHAR>)\d+(?::\d+)?(?=<\/CHAR>)
```

Java string:

```
 String pattern = "(?<=<CHAR>)\\d+(?::\\d+)?(?=</CHAR>)";
```

Sample code:

```
String str = "<MSG><KEY>name.extObject</KEY><PARAM><CHAR>Number</CHAR><CHAR>7015:188188</CHAR></PARAM></MSG>";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?<=<CHAR>)\\d+(?::\\d+)?(?=</CHAR>)");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
7015:188188
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` in Java regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = inputString;
String result="";
while(s.indexOf("<CHAR>") != -1)
{
    result += s.substring(s.indexOf("<CHAR>") + "<CHAR>".length(), s.indexOf("</CHAR>")) + " ";
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("</CHAR>") + "</CHAR>".length());
}

//result is now the desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex for that is : (.*?)</CHAR>

However, it is better to use an XML parser for that.